# Clientside javascript unpack value from asynchronous call

Tags: javascript, http, client-server

I have the following code on my client server, connected to a node.js server:

```js
async function updateHTML(text){
    const response = await ServerHandshake(text);
    console.log("done");
    let script = document.createElement("script");
    script.text = response;
    document.body.appendChild(script);
}


async function ServerHandshake(text){
    // POST
    fetch('/text', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            text: text
        })
    })
        .then(function(response){
            if(response.ok){
                console.log('POST success.');
                return;
            }
            throw new Error('POST failed.');
        })
        .catch(function(error){
            console.log(error);
        });

    // GET
    fetch('/processed', {method: 'GET'})
        .then(function(response){
            if(response.ok){
                console.log("GET success.");
                return response.json();
            }
            throw new Error('GET failed.');
        })
        .then(function(data){
            let returnValue = data.result;
            console.log(returnValue);
            return returnValue;
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        });

}

(async function(){
    await updateHTML("hello, world!");
})();
```

The console logs the return value of `serverHandshake`, but the html file after the async call shows `undefined`.

"Done" is also printed first; it seems like that should be printed later, but somehow await is not properly working.

What's the properly way to do this?

Note I am asking about client-side, not server-side

Comment: Do you realize that you are doing a POST to `/text` and a GET of `/processed` **at the same time**?  If you intended the GET of `/processed` to be done *after* the server responds from the POST to `/text` then your braces for your `.then` are in the wrong place or you should have awaited your fetch.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are mixing up callback-style (with `.then()`) and await-style, that's why it doesn't work.

Remove all `.then()` and use it this way :

```
async function updateHTML(text){
    const response = await ServerHandshake(text);
    
    if(response.ok){
        console.log('POST success.');
    }

}


function ServerHandshake(text){
    return fetch( ... ); // this can be awaited
}
```